# how count the most True that are followed by each other?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a true false in each row. how I can count Trues whose are followed each other and select its max??

example:

```
True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,True
```

answer:

```
4,6,1 ----> the answer is 6!
```

Well I have a data frame and I have to do that for each row:

```
    diff0   diff1   diff2   diff3   diff4   diff5   diff6   diff7   diff8   diff9
0   True    True    True    False   True    False   False   True    False   True
1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
3   True    False   False   False   True    False   True    False   False   False
4   True    False   True    False   False   True    False   False   False   False
```

For an example the first row is 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
lst = [True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,True]
from itertools import groupby
>>> max(sum(1 for i in c if i) for n, c in groupby(lst))
6
```

Edit: To implement this for each row of your DataFrame, you can do:

```
df["seq"] = df.apply(lambda x: max(sum(1 for i in c if i) for n, c in groupby(x)), axis=1)
>>> df
   diff0  diff1  diff2  diff3  diff4  diff5  diff6  diff7  diff8  diff9  seq
0   True   True   True  False   True  False  False   True  False   True    3
1  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False    0
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False    0
3   True  False  False  False   True  False   True  False  False  False    1
4   True  False   True  False  False   True  False  False  False  False    1
```

Comment: can you explain the answer?

Comment: This is really just a direct application of `groupby` from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: I have to do that for each row of a data Fram! could u please tell me what I should do?

Comment: Post a sample of your dataframe in your question please.

Answer (score 2):

- `groupby()` where there's a change in sequence
- get length of each sequence using `count()`
- then its the `max()` length sequence

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"seq":[True,True,True,True,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,True]})

df.groupby((df["seq"]!=df["seq"].shift()).cumsum()).count().max()
```

#### output

```
seq    6
dtype: int64
```

#### row by row instead of single column

- changed `agg()` function from `count()` to `sum()` so only **True** is considered

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    diff0   diff1   diff2   diff3   diff4   diff5   diff6   diff7   diff8   diff9
0   True    True    True    False   True    False   False   True    False   True
1   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
2   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False   False
3   True    False   False   False   True    False   True    False   False   False
4   True    False   True    False   False   True    False   False   False   False"""), sep="\s+")

dft = df.T
df["maxslen"] = [dft.groupby((dft[c]!=dft[c].shift()).cumsum()).sum().max()[c] for c in dft.columns]
```

#### output

| diff0 | diff1 | diff2 | diff3 | diff4 | diff5 | diff6 | diff7 | diff8 | diff9 | maxslen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True | False | True | False | False | True | False | True | 3 |
| False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | 0 |
| False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | 0 |
| True | False | False | False | True | False | True | False | False | False | 1 |
| True | False | True | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | 1 |

Comment: I should do it for each row and not column

Comment: best if you provide better sample data,  you should just need to use `transpose()` as well

Comment: I am confused why I get this: ValueError: Length of values (3186) does not match length of index (5)

Comment: I've just changed again using your sample data

Comment: This doesn't distinguish between consecutive `True`s or `False`s, does it? i.e., for your first example, if you do `df.seq ^= True` and then your code, result is still 6.

Comment: correct - minor change again,  use `sum()` instead of `count()`, **True** is equivalent to **1** and **False** is **0**

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby from itertools

```
from itertools import groupby

max(sum(1 for v in vals) for k, vals in groupby(bools) if k)
```

Comment: If I have a data frame, then I should put `df` in `bools`?